# Understanding defaults in `np.ndarray` subclassing

Tags: python, numpy, subclass

I am working through the [`numpy` documentation on subclassing `ndarray`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.subclassing.html), but I am observing a slightly different result than what is described, regarding setting default values. The doc appears to say that one location should be used to set your default for an extra attribute, but I am finding that maintaining the correct default in two locations is necessary.

Consider the [realistic example](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.subclassing.html#slightly-more-realistic-example-attribute-added-to-existing-array) described in the doc, reproduced here (the comments have been reformatted for brevity):

```
import numpy as np

class RealisticInfoArray(np.ndarray):

    def __new__(cls, input_array, info=None):
        obj = np.asarray(input_array).view(cls)
        obj.info = info
        return obj

    def __array_finalize__(self, obj):
        # Note that it is here, rather than in the __new__ method,
        # that we set the default value for 'info', because this
        # method sees all creation of default objects - with the
        # InfoArray.__new__ constructor, but also with
        # arr.view(InfoArray).
        if obj is None: return
        self.info = getattr(obj, 'info', None)
```

The comment describing where the default value takes effect is confusing me. I replaced the default values to see what was going on, as such: `info='michelangelo'` in `__new__` and `getattr(obj, 'info', 'donatello')` in `__array_finalize__`. I find that the latter is only set with the `view` creation method, and the former is used for explicit constructor calls and from-template creation:

```
>>> a = RealisticInfoArray(np.arange(10)); print(a.info)
michelangelo
>>> b = np.arange(10).view(RealisticInfoArray); print(b.info)
donatello
>>> c = a[1:]; print(c.info)
michelangelo
```

In this case, it looks like `a` is taking the "wrong" default, according to my reading of the doc. From what I can tell, `a.info` is set correctly in `__array_finalize__`, but then is overwritten with the default from `__new__`.

First, have I made a mistake? And if not, do I need to maintain the intended default in both places, or is there a way to reduce it to one? (I have made an attempt at this in my answer below, any feedback is appreciated.)

Answer (score 0):

My current workaround for this (other than maintaining two default values), is to provide a class attribute, `DEFAULT_INFO`, that can be accessed by both `__new__` and `__array_finalize__`:

```
import numpy as np

class RealisticInfoArray(np.ndarray):

    DEFAULT_INFO = 'michelangelo'

    def __new__(cls, input_array, info=None):
        obj = np.asarray(input_array).view(cls)
        if info is None:
            info = obj.DEFAULT_INFO
        obj.info = info
        return obj

    def __array_finalize__(self, obj):
        if obj is None: return
        self.info = getattr(obj, 'info', self.DEFAULT_INFO)
```

which correctly produces:

```
>>> a = RealisticInfoArray(np.arange(10)); print(a.info)
michelangelo
>>> b = np.arange(10).view(RealisticInfoArray); print(b.info)
michelangelo
>>> c = a[1:]; print(c.info)
michelangelo
```

This also has the added benefit that a user of the class can modify the default value (e.g. `RealisticInfoArray.DEFAULT_INFO = 'leonardo'`), and use their own default value as they see fit. However, I have not tested this solution for unintended side-effects.